# What open source miner applications are there?

Tags: mining-setup, miner-configuration, mining-software

What open source miner applications are there? Especially to see how the mining process works.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the user is asking for a list that may not be complete, hence it is unlikely that an answer is found that is satisfying.

Answer (score 20):

The official list is on [The Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Software#Mining_apps) and is constantly being modified since new software shows up fairly often, but here's the quick breakdown:

- Poclbm - Python/OpenCL GPU miner (GUI)
- DiabloMiner - Java/OpenCL GPU miner (MAC OS X GUI)
- RPC Miner - remote RPC miner (MAC OS X GUI)
- Phoenix miner - miner
- Cpu Miner - miner
- Ufasoft miner - miner
- Pyminer - Python miner, reference implementation
- Remote miner - mining pool software
- Open Source FGPA Bitcoin Miner - a miner that makes use of an FPGA Board

[Poclbm](https://github.com/m0mchil/poclbm/archives/master) and [Phoenix](https://xp-dev.com/svn/phoenix-miner/files/) are probably the most popular (links go to the sources) though that's based more on my opinion than any facts or studies. In either case, both should shed some light on the mining process.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Codler. I copied and pasted way too quickly and didn't check my output carefully enough :)

Comment: You shouldn't mention poclbm-mod. It's long outdated and is no longer maintained.

Comment: poclbm-mod has been removed, thanks.

Answer (score 19):

jzgarzik wrote a very basic miner in Python. It is slow on purpose, because it shows how a simple miner works (and the mining process). It can also be reused as boilerplate code (the getwork JSON-RPC command).

https://github.com/jgarzik/pyminer/blob/master/pyminer.py

Comment: Why the downvote? This tutorial miner was *especially* done to show how the mining process works. That answers the question perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

GPU Miners

```
DiabloMiner - https://github.com/Diablo-D3/DiabloMiner

poclbm      - https://github.com/m0mchil/poclbm

hashkill    - 64-bit http://www.gat3way.eu/poc/hashkill-0.2.4-x86_64.tgz 

              32-bit http://www.gat3way.eu/poc/hashkill-0.2.4-x86.tgz   

Phoenix     - https://github.com/jedi95/Phoenix-Miner
```

CPU Miners

```
Jgarzik     - https://github.com/jgarzik/cpuminer.git

Ufasoft     - http://ufasoft.com/open/bitcoin/

FPGAminer   - https://github.com/progranism/Open-Source-FPGA-Bitcoin-Miner
```

Answer (score 2):

[Phoenix](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=6458.0) is a very good GPU miner. While I couldn't find the exact license, it's source is available on GitHub: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=6458.0

Well, it's written in python, so you could see the source anyways. However, it's actually quite easy to understand and modify, e.g. to create your own logging interface.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious open-source mining application is the official Bitcoin client itself, available at: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin

The source code is well written and shows quite clearly the way that hashing is performed in order to mine new blocks. It is however a CPU-only algorithm, and doesn't use some of the more advanced mechanisms for accelerating the hashing process.

Despite this, it definitely offers a good introduction into how the generation of blocks, hashing etc. works, without the added overhead of having to deal with potentially unfamiliar GPU-based mining code, which is intentially highly optimised and as a result will likely to be more difficult to understand, and make the basic concepts more difficult to follow.

Answer (score 2):

You can see how mining process works here
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/contrib/pyminer

Answer (score 1):

CPU miner in PHP - https://github.com/codler/Bitcoin-phpMiner

Comment: Beware this is not a true "miner" it just use a curl call to the following server  http://api.bitp.it/work?

Comment: @Sydwell, it is a true miner, it is connecting to a pool mining of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/colinrgodsey/scalaminer

Written in scala, mostly just mining device control for connecting with pools

Answer (score 0):

[M0mchil's poclbm](https://github.com/m0mchil/poclbm), written in python, hosted on github.

Answer (score 0):

[Poclbm](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Poclbm): An open source, python based GPU miner.

[Open Source FPGA Miner](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=9047.0): The name says it all.  Hit the source for the project.