# What is the easiest to operate/fastest solo bitcoin mining client for a cluster rig?

Tags: client, solo-mining, mining-software

I'm planning to set up a rig and need a **solo mining** client. Can you offer me some suggestions? (Please don't just tell me that solo mining isn't worth it).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a GPU rig cluster, you ought to look at standard miners. This question should help you get started:

[What open source miner applications are there?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-open-source-miner-applications-are-there)

In the end you ought to try a few of them out and see which ones give you the best performance on your hardware. You can also have a look at [Mining hardware comparison Wiki page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison) to see what performance you should expect from your hardware and what configuration was used to accomplish it.