# Bitcoin Miner Pseudo code

Tags: mining-software, mining-technical-details

I want to understand how the mining process works so that I can code up my own bitcoin miner. Does anybody have pseudo code of a bitcoin miner that will help me achieve this?

Also, help with an implementation in C++ will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following:

[What open source miner applications are there?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-open-source-miner-applications-are-there)

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Software#Mining_apps

https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer